# Using bulkCreate with updateOnDuplicate always inserts new rows into the DB

Tags: node.js, express, mariadb, sequelize.js

A project I've inherited is using sequelize 6.12.5 as part of an Express + MariaDB backend. When a user updates any of their data on the front end, the row is duplicated in the DB, but with the new values as opposed to the existing row being updated.

As it stands, this is the code for the particular part of the system that has this issue:

```
    //Create Bulk Entries
    const reportEntries =  await ReportEntry.bulkCreate(entries, {
      ignoreDuplicates: true,
      updateOnDuplicate: ['input_section_id', 'input_item_id', 'quantity', 'input_const', 'total']
    })
    return res.status(201).json({ entries: reportEntries });
```

And the ReportEntry model is defined as follows:

```
ReportEntry.init({
    facility_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    business_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    input_section_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    input_item_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    input_const: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10,3),
    quantity: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10,3),
    total: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10,3),
    is_offset: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    year: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    quarter: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'ReportEntry',
    tableName: 'ch_report_entries',
    underscored: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at'
  });
```

I've been through the sequelize docs [here](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel#static-method-bulkCreate) and as far as I can tell, everything looks fine, but it clearly isn't working.

Is there something fundamentally missing from this code, or should I be looking elsewhere in my troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken, but ignoring duplicates means sequelize will not throw an error (it will throw when finding duplicate without this option - or "update on duplicate" option - used). In your case I would say you should NOT use this option.
It's also not clear how new rows could be created if you have primary key references in your entries array...

Comment: Thanks Michael! I've tried this but still no dice. According to the docs, there isn't a minimum required version for MariaDB support, so I don't think that is the case either.